$\int\frac{\sin 2x\sin 3x}{\sin 2x+\sin 3x}\,\mathrm dx$
$$\int\frac{\sin 2x\sin 3x}{\sin 2x+\sin 3x}\,\mathrm dx$$
My attempt:
Rewriting the numerator:
We can use the double angle identity for sine:
$$\sin(A)\sin(B) = \frac12\left(\cos(A - B) - \cos(A + B)\right)$$
Here, let $A = 2x$ and $B = 3x$. Substitute these values into the identity:
$$\sin(2x)\sin(3x) = \frac12(\cos(2x - 3x) - \cos(2x + 3x))$$
Apply this identity to rewrite the numerator:
$$\sin^2(x)\sin(3x) = \frac12(\cos(x) - \cos(5x))$$
Now I am stuck here

Please format your equations

https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference Please format your answers using MathJax (tutorial linked above).  As it stands now, it is difficult to read what you have written.

If there is no limit on the integral, isn't the result 0 since, f(x)=-f(-x) where f(x) is your integrand?

You may use the known identities $$\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$$$$\sin(3x)=3\cos^2(x)\sin(x)-\sin^3(x)$$
The integral is thus the same as $$\int\dfrac{2\sin(x)\cos(x)(3\cos^2(x)\sin(x)-\sin^3(x))}{2\sin(x)\cos(x)+3\cos^2(x)\sin(x)-\sin^3(x)}dx=\int\dfrac{2\sin(x)\cos(x)(3\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x))}{2\cos(x)+3\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)}dx$$
Using that $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$ we get $$\int\dfrac{2\sin(x)\cos(x)(3\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x))}{2\cos(x)+3\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)}dx=\int\dfrac{2\sin(x)\cos(x)(4\cos^2(x)-1)}{2\cos(x)+4\cos^2(x)-1}dx$$
Letting $u=\cos(x)$ the integral transforms into $$-\int\dfrac{2u(4u^2-1)}{2u+4u^2-1}\,du$$
This is a rational integral that can be solved using the standard methods: long division, partial fractions, etc.

If you use $x=2\tan^{-1}(t)$ you end with
$$\int -\frac{8 (t-1) t (t+1) \left(t^2-3\right) \left(3
   t^2-1\right)}{\left(t^2+1\right)^3 \left(t^4-10
   t^2+5\right)}\,dt $$ Partial fraction decomposition gives
$$\int \Bigg(\frac{t}{t^2+1}-\frac{12
   t}{\left(t^2+1\right)^2}+\frac{16
   t}{\left(t^2+1\right)^3}-\frac{t^3+t}{t^4-10 t^2+5}   \Bigg)\,dt$$
For the last one
$$\frac{t^3+t}{t^4-10 t^2+5}=\frac{t^3+t}{\left(t^2-2 \sqrt{5}-5\right) \left(t^2+2
   \sqrt{5}-5\right)  }= $$
$$\frac{\left(\sqrt{5}-3\right) t}{2 \sqrt{5} \left(t^2+2
   \sqrt{5}-5\right)}-\frac{\left(3+\sqrt{5}\right) t}{2
   \sqrt{5} \left(-t^2+2 \sqrt{5}+5\right)}$$
